# Remove Category bar in PreferenceScreen

Tags: android

How do you remove the category bar that displays in the PreferenceScreen? I have my own custom view for that, so I want to get rid of it altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would this help? [Android – Hidding the status and title bar of your application](http://www.vogella.de/blog/2011/02/28/android-hidding-the-status-and-title-bar/)